# Why would a program compiled for a SPARC ISA read an integer differently than on a Pentium ISA?

Tags: memory, data-structures, sparc

A program compiled for a SPARC ISA writes a 32-bit unsigned integer 0xABCDEF01 to a file, and reads it back correctly. The same program compiled for a Pentium ISA also works correctly. However, when the file is transferred, the program incorrectly reads the integer from the file as 0x01EFCDAB. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPARC and Pentium use a different byte ordering ("endianness") in memory and on storage:

- SPARC uses **big-endian**: the most-significant byte of the integer comes first
- Pentium uses **little-endian**: the least-significant byte of the integer comes first

I.e. when the file is transferred to machine with a different endianness, the bytes of an integer seem to be in a reversed order.